# ASP.Net Identity SSO multiple applications

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have two applications using MVC Core 2.2 with Entity and Identity
These two applications need to use the same user base. All applications and database are on the same server.
Permissions and roles will be different per site, my main goal is SSO (Single Sign On).
In this case, do I need to use some tool like Identity Server 4? Or can I do it in a simpler way?

Comment: This is the case for OAuth - accessing multiple applications with a single centralized identity. Where the identity comes from could be consumer apps like Google/Facebook, corporate like Azure AD, or your own like IdentityServer or OpenIddict.

Comment: I agree with @NoahStahl and I think you'd better choose a tool to achieve your goal sir, such as [azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on)

Comment: Ok, but my user base has both internal and external people, is Azure AD still the best option?
Can't I just use the identity with the AspNetUserLogins options?

Comment: "Best option" would depend on a lot of things, hard to say with limited info. It's unfortunately a fairly complex topic that requires lots of research. I've never found it simple. :)

Comment: Okay, I'm going to use IdentityServer4.
I understand with this framework, it will be possible to have login and SSO from a single base for multiple applications and APIs. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response and, its ok to use identity server 4 as you said.